# Using C:forEach to iterate over two variables

Tags: jsp, servlets

I m sending two attributes using request.setAttribute() method, which are both list , one with username, and one with their corresponging fullname. I receive them using EL syntax.
Servlet code

```
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchUserQuery);

            List<String> fullNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> userNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                fullNameList.add(rs.getString("firstname") + " " +  rs.getString("lastname"));
                userNameList.add(rs.getString("username"));
            }

            request.setAttribute("fullNameList", fullNameList);
            request.setAttribute("userNameList", userNameList);

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            //response.getWriter().write(fullNameList);


            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("searchResults");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Here is part of my code for jsp

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${fullNameList}">
                                <c:set var="username" value="${userNameList}" />
                                <li class="list-group-item title"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UserProfile?username=${username}"><strong>${list}</strong></a></li>
                        </c:forEach>
```

I need to retrieve a single var 'username' that corresponds to single 'list' variable. So I think i need  to iterate everytime and get two variables 'list' and 'username'.I used c:set coz i didnt how to get done what i required.

Please help. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two `List<String>` create just one `List<User>` where `User` is a simple POJO class having `firstName`, `lastName` and `userName`.

For example:

POJO:

```
public class User {
     private String firstName, lastName, userName;
     // getter & setter
}
```

Servlet:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
// populate users
request.setAttribute("users", users);
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items=${users}>
    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UserProfile?username=${user.userName}"><strong>${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</strong></a></li>
</c:forEach>
```